# Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'summary'

Tags: statistics, rlang

I'm trying to implement an existing code on Github but i still get an error that I don't know where it did came from or how to fix it. Here is the function :

```
AdstockRate<-function(Data,Impact,Ads){
            modFit<-nls(data=Data,Impact~a+b*adstock(Ads,rate),
            start<-c(a=1,b=1,rate=0))
            if(summary(modFit)$coefficients[3,1]>0){
            AdstockRate=summary(modfit)$coefficients[3,1]
            }
            else{
            library(minpack.lm)
            nls.out<-nlsLM(Impact~a+b*adstock(Ads,rate),data=Data,start=list(a=1,b=1,rate=0),
            lower<-c(a=-Inf,b=-Inf,rate=0),upper=c(a=Inf,b=Inf,rate=1))
            AdstockRate<-summary(nls.out)$coefficients[3,1]
            }
            return(AdstockRate)
            }
```

I got this error :

Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'summary': object 'modfit' not found

Thank you in advance.

Comment: typo: mod**f**it